# Conditional filtering in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to filter an array based on user selection from multiple drop downs. However, if a user does not make a selection from a drop down I do not want to use that drop down's value as a filter. Is there a way to do this without writing a bunch of `if/else` statements?

This is what I have but I'm wondering if it can be condensed.

```
filterOptions() {
      if (this.name != undefined && this.age != undefined) {
        this.filteredOptions = this.Options
          .filter(x => x.name == this.name)
          .filter(x => x.age == this.age);
      } else if (this.name == undefined && this.age != undefined) {
        this.filteredOptions = this.Options
          .filter(x => x.age == this.age);
      } else if (this.name != undefined && this.age == undefined) {
        this.filteredOptions = this.Options
          .filter(x => x.flcaLoan == this.name);
      } else {
        this.filteredOptions = this.Options;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just put it in one filter, like so:

```
this.Options.filter(x => {
  if (this.name && this.name != x.name) {
    return false; // remove if name is set and name doesn't match
  } else if (this.age && this.age != x.age) {
    return false; // remove if age is set and age doesn't match
  }

  return true; // keep
}
```